# Updating record doesn't work the second time and more bizarre behavior in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to parse sentences and save each word in a database, keeping a count of how many times each word appears. For that, I have an `Info` model, with the attributes `word` and `count`. If `word` exists, increment `count`; if not, create `word` and set `count` to `1`. Simple, right?

Well. Here's the relevant code:

```
def parse entry
  word = entry[:base]

  if Info.exists?(word: word)
    old_word = Info.where(word: word)
    new_count = old_word.count + 1
    old_word.count = new_count
    old_word.save
  else
    new_word = Info.new(word: word, count: 1)
    new_word.save
  end
end
```

This returns the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `count=' for #<Info::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xb7c83e8> 
Did you mean?  count):
```

I'm pretty sure I've used this syntax before, and according to [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#update), it should work:

```
user = User.find_by(name: 'David')
user.name = 'Dave'
user.save
```

But there's a different syntax for the same operation, so let's give it a try:

```
def parse entry
  word = entry[:base]

  if Info.exists?(word: word)
    old_word = Info.where(word: word)
    new_count = old_word.count + 1
    old_word.update(count: new_count)
  else
    new_word = Info.new(word: word, count: 1)
    new_word.save
  end
end
```

Now it works, in the sense that Rails doesn't complain and the records are created. However, it only updates the `count` up to `2` instances. Any more than that and simply nothing happens. Here's an example:

Inserting the first sentence with new word `new`:

```
Info Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "infos" WHERE "infos"."word" = ? LIMIT ?  [["word", "new"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "infos" ("word", "count", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["word", "new"], ["count", 1], ["created_at", "2018-01-16 20:20:38.078146"], ["updated_at", "2018-01-16 20:20:38.078146"]]
(130.1ms)  commit transaction
```

You can see it checks whether the word exists, then creates the new record.

Inserting the second sentence with the now already existing word `new`:

```
Info Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "infos" WHERE "infos"."word" = ? LIMIT ?  [["word", "new"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "infos" WHERE "infos"."word" = ?  [["word", "new"]]
Info Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "infos".* FROM "infos" WHERE "infos"."word" = ?  [["word", "new"]]
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
SQL (4.0ms)  UPDATE "infos" SET "count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "infos"."id" = ?  [["count", 2], ["updated_at", "2018-01-16 20:21:28.310815"], ["id", 5]]
(14.0ms)  commit transaction
```

You can see it checks for the existence of the word, sees it already exists and so begins the transaction to **update** the record with the new count.

Now, this is what happens when you insert the word `new` a *third* time:

```
Info Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "infos" WHERE "infos"."word" = ? LIMIT ?  [["word", "new"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "infos" WHERE "infos"."word" = ?  [["word", "new"]]
Info Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "infos".* FROM "infos" WHERE "infos"."word" = ?  [["word", "new"]]
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  commit transaction
```

You can see it checks for the existence of the word, sees it already exists and just seemingly ignores the `update` command. The `count` attribute just stops being updated from now on.

What is going on? Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: `.where()` returns an ActiveRecord query, not a result. Try `.find_by_word(word)`, and everything will fall into place. Your code is currently confused by the ActiveRecord `.count` method, which means to count records in a query, not your database's table's `count` field.

Comment: Hah! Worked like a charm, thank you!